# Can the internal counter of a Scratch Repeat block be accessed?

Tags: repeat, data-access, control-structure, mit-scratch, loop-counter

I assume that the [`Repeat()` block in Scratch](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Repeat_()_(block)) has some kind of internal counter that increments or decrements at the beginning or end of each time around the block.

Can the value of this counter be accessed in any way?

I realize [this](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Repeat_()_(block)#Workaround) can be done to have an available counter, but I am only interested in this for potential similar implementation in a different language that I help develop.

Comment: Not from within Scratch, but if you're designing a language, you of course could make it accessible. I also recommend taking a look at [Snap!](http://snap.berkeley.edu/), a language based on Scratch; specifically, import the tools library and look at the repeat block from there - it comes with a counter.

Answer (score 1):

No, but variables are your friend:

```
set counter to 0
repeat times
  change counter by 1
  ...
end
```

Should be fairly self descriptive :)

Now you don't even need to look at an "internal counter"!

Comment: But... I asked about the internal counter!

Comment: @NBZ What's the difference? Why should you need to use the internal counter?

Comment: You must have missed my note below the horizontal ruler. I increased the font size now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, sort of...

There is a block, called the `foreach` block, which works just like the `repeat` block except you can choose a variable to set the loop counter to.

It was removed from the block listing in the early Scratch 2.0 beta, and not many people know about it, but here is a working example on the Scratch website: [For each v in number](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/48023824/). Note that it doesn't use `%m.list` internally, so you have to change the JSON of the project with something like [ScratchEdit](http://dx.dylan4.com/ScratchEdit/) or a text editor to pick a variable other than `v`.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. It seems that the correct answer is "No, you cannot!".

Comment: @NBZ It's a repeat, just with a way to access the internal variable. I think it's pretty much the same. (But no, this doesn't *strictly* answer the question!)